# one backslash taken as two backslashes by python

Tags: python

I want to pass the path to a result location to my python script pass as argument.But here my difficuty is python is converting one backslah to two backslashes.

i know its done to play safe to remove the special characters behaviour,but dont want this behaviour , since my path is getting changed , how do i resolve this.

ex: if the path i give is

\\perf-host.xyz.com\b_disk\Automation\resultDir .... then its parsed as

\\\\perf-host.xyz.com\\b_disk\\Automation\\resultDir

```
def check_arg(args=None):

   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Script to learn basic argparse')

   parser.add_argument('-i', '--inputfile',
                    help='txt file that contains the frame names',
                    required='True')

   parser.add_argument('-o', '--outputpath',
                    help='path to the result directory where captured aubs need to be stored',
                    required='True')

   _args = parser.parse_args(args)

   return (_args.inputfile,_args.outputpath)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   _input,_output = check_arg(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Did you try raw strings, e.g. `r"\\perf-host.xyz.com\b_disk\Automation\resultDir"`? Be careful not to end your string with a backslash though.

Comment: Why are you using `repr`?  Are you having the same problem with both `inputfile` and `outputpath`?

Comment: @mwormser : i cant use raw strings becuse i can pass raw strign from the commandline, even if i tried passing as raw in that case also its the same behaviour.

Comment: Yes Eric,I am having the same problem with inputfile and outputpath.
"repr" was there by mistake i was trying something, but _input,_output as given to me by replacing one backslash by two backslashes.